# Preventing Elastic Beanstalk from Creating a Portal_deploy Folder in .NET Framework Application Deployment

Tags: .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm facing an issue while deploying my .NET Framework application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The problem is that when I deploy my application (Portal.zip), Elastic Beanstalk creates a folder named "Portal_deploy" under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and places another `web.config` file in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, which includes a rewrite rule as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="AWS_BEANSTALK" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^(https?://[^/]+/)Portal_deploy" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/Portal_deploy" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}Portal_deploy{PATH_INFO}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rewrite rule adds "Portal_deploy" to my URLs, which is not the behavior I want. I would prefer that all the files from Portal.zip are placed directly in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and not within a "Portal_deploy" subfolder.

I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I prevent Elastic Beanstalk from creating the "Portal_deploy" folder during deployment?
2. Why does Elastic Beanstalk automatically create this folder, and is there a way to configure or disable this behavior?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are you deploying it with? `eb deploy`? We need to see the full commands you're using (or if you're using the VS plugins)